# JDT: Missing semicolon when replacing a MethodInvocation with another

Tags: java, eclipse-jdt, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to use Eclipse JDT's AST model to replace one `MethodInvocation` with another. To take a trivial example - I'm trying to replace all calls to `Log.(i/e/d/w)` with calls to `System.out.println()`. I'm using an `ASTVisitor` to locate the *interesting* `ASTNode` and replace it with the new `MethodInvocation` node. Here's an outline of the code:

```
class StatementVisitor extends ASTVisitor {

    @Override
    public boolean visit(ExpressionStatement node) {

        // If node is a MethodInvocation statement and method
        // name is i/e/d/w while class name is Log

        // Code omitted for brevity

        AST ast = node.getAST();
        MethodInvocation newMethodInvocation = ast.newMethodInvocation();
        if (newMethodInvocation != null) {
            newMethodInvocation.setExpression(
                ast.newQualifiedName(
                    ast.newSimpleName("System"), 
                    ast.newSimpleName("out")));
            newMethodInvocation.setName(ast.newSimpleName("println"));

            // Copy the params over to the new MethodInvocation object
            mASTRewrite.replace(node, newMethodInvocation, null);
        }
    }
}
```

This rewrite is then saved back to the original document. This whole thing is working fine, but for one small problem - the original statement:

```
Log.i("Hello There");
```

changes to:

```
System.out.println("Hello There")
```

**NOTE**: Semicolon at the end of the statement is missing

**QUESTION**: How do I insert the semicolon at the end of the new statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer. The trick is to wrap the `newMethodInvocation` object in an object of type `ExpressionStatement` like so:

```
ExpressionStatement statement = ast.newExpressionStatement(newMethodInvocation);
mASTRewrite.replace(node, statement, null);
```

Essentially, replace the last line in my code sample with the above two lines.